# Date Class Altered After Calling R.ts

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: a date column and an observation column.
Here is the head:

[image]

I call ts with this line of code

```
data_grp_ts = ts(data_grp, frequency = 52)
```

And when I look at the head of the resulting time series, the date is gone:

[image]

There is 2 years of data in the data frame (104 observations) and the resulting time series index is unexpected

```
index(data_grp_ts)
```

[image]

Is there something wrong with the original date format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may extract the column i.e. `data_grp[[2]]` and apply the `ts` or convert to `tsibble` object with `min/max` of dates in `start`, `end`

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
[rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not enough info in the post for people to answer this, I am closing it and will re-open a new post with more detail.  It is found here:  [Working With Weekly Time Series Data In R using xts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017456/working-with-weekly-time-series-data-in-r-using-xts)