# Working With Weekly Time Series Data In R using xts

Tags: r

Here is a sample dataframe with data observed weekly (Saturday).

[image]

There are 104 observations in the dataframe

[image]

And #52 is the last observation in 2020 and #53 is the first observation in 2021:

[image]

I am attempting to decompose it for a year over year analysis:

```
data <- read.csv ("sum_data.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
data_xts <- xts(data$total_encounters, data$date, start = (2020-01-04), frequency = 52)
head(data_xts)
index(data_xts)
periodicity(data_xts)
frequency(data_xts) #0.14 is wrong, S/B 2
nweeks(data_xts)
plot(data_xts, ylab = "dod_cli_encounters")
xts_data_decomp <- decompose(data_xts, type = "mult")
plot(xts_data_decomp)
```

However, when I run the decompose function, I get the following error:

> time series has no or less than 2 periods

I did notice that the frequency function returns 0.1428 and it should be 2.  How do I let xts know that this is a weekly dataset that should be treated as such?

Here is the dput:

```
 data <- 
 structure(list(X = 1:104, date = structure(c(18265, 18272, 18279, 
 18286, 18293, 18300, 18307, 18314, 18321, 18328, 18335, 18342,  18349,
 18356, 18363, 18370, 18377, 18384, 18391, 18398, 18405,  18412, 18419,
 18426, 18433, 18440, 18447, 18454, 18461, 18468,  18475, 18482, 18489,
 18496, 18503, 18510, 18517, 18524, 18531,  18538, 18545, 18552, 18559,
 18566, 18573, 18580, 18587, 18594,  18601, 18608, 18615, 18622, 18629,
 18636, 18643, 18650, 18657,  18664, 18671, 18678, 18685, 18692, 18699,
 18706, 18713, 18720,  18727, 18734, 18741, 18748, 18755, 18762, 18769,
 18776, 18783,  18790, 18797, 18804, 18811, 18818, 18825, 18832, 18839,
 18846,  18853, 18860, 18867, 18874, 18881, 18888, 18895, 18902, 18909,
 18916, 18923, 18930, 18937, 18944, 18951, 18958, 18965, 18972,  18979,
 18986), class = "Date"), total_encounters = c(287906L,  549315L,
 520135L, 448754L, 535075L, 529320L, 501597L, 437590L,  535149L,
 533067L, 515730L, 483225L, 401350L, 348270L, 299971L,  276799L,
 277489L, 289127L, 305620L, 320805L, 323691L, 298987L,  377737L,
 385446L, 399777L, 412889L, 328152L, 413512L, 428903L,  439043L,
 419405L, 426545L, 434972L, 432648L, 441663L, 416962L,  374311L,
 450942L, 461086L, 473937L, 462994L, 416820L, 502248L,  486632L,
 493260L, 415058L, 522538L, 325256L, 516749L, 498325L,  487383L,
 263927L, 275647L, 525448L, 523922L, 444946L, 538128L,  545296L,
 507652L, 401458L, 566012L, 555483L, 543088L, 523277L,  553983L,
 528812L, 520043L, 524375L, 518190L, 501871L, 504872L,  508024L,
 505778L, 457917L, 399435L, 482569L, 450510L, 455820L,  425968L,
 365471L, 459818L, 464688L, 466636L, 473430L, 479059L,  478048L,
 495112L, 471965L, 416111L, 494969L, 490780L, 488221L,  477747L,
 419577L, 501869L, 498140L, 486291L, 399430L, 508608L,  305376L,
 509681L, 486055L, 466249L, 298166L)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -104L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I put it into the question.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

decompose requires that a full cycle must be represented as 1 unit whereas Date class represents 1 day as 1 unit so to have a year as the cycle for use with decompose xts is not applicable. Use ts instead.  Assuming that the data begins at the first week of the year and that there are 52 weeks in each year we have the following.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(data[-1])
tt <- ts(z, start = as.yearmon(start(z)), freq = 52)
tt.d <- decompose(tt)

library(xts)
x <- as.xts(z)
```

For plotting plot(tt), plot(z) and plot(x) all work. We show the plots corresponding to the following code.

```
plot(tt)
plot(tt.d)
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]